# slider of WordPress option tree framwork need tinyMCE editor

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on slider of option tree framework theme mode, but I need the slider description field as rich tinymce editor, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple text area instead of textarea.

```
array(
    'id'          => 'demo_textarea_simple',
    'label'       => __( 'Textarea Simple', 'theme-text-domain' ),
    'desc'        => __( 'The Textarea Simple option type is a large string value used for custom code or text in the theme. The Textarea Simple does not have a WYSIWYG editor.', 'theme-text-domain' ),
    'std'         => '',
    'type'        => 'textarea-simple',
    'section'     => 'option_types',
  ),
```